# Data Grid Server On Development Computer With SSL

Tags: redhat, infinispan

I am doing some kind of poc on my development machine. I downloaded Red Hat Data Grid 8.2 Server and installed unzipping it. I edited infinispan.xml file and removed the comments on tag to enable TSL. Then I started the server locally using server.bat. But when I browse to 127.0.0.1:11222 I cannot browse data grid server administration console. I guess, it is because I enabled TSL and I don't know how I can browse the console.

P.s: If I don't enable TSL I can connect data grid server administration console

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't set a custom Keystore, Infinispan will generate a self-signed certificate.

Usually, self-signed certificates are blocked by the browser;
so, make sure the browser isn't blocking the connection and that you are connecting to https://127.0.0.1:11222.

More information in the [Documentation](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/server/server.html#endpoint-encryption).